# How to put popups on clicking a pin present at google map

Tags: android, google-maps

In my app I am using Google Maps. On clicking a pin on Google Map we have to get an popup at that position. But I am using custom dialog it display the message at center of the mapview. How do I display a popup instead of dialog at the position we have clicked? Please give me a complete example in Android.

Answer (score 0):

STEPS:

1. Create an absolute layout
2. Set it as invisible
3. When ever you tap the event set it as visible
4. Make sure that you will set layout parameters
5. Add this view to object of map view

Answer (score 0):

Try this

https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-mapviewballoons#readme